# Javascript: Splitting string without .split( ) method?

Tags: javascript, function, methods, split, refactoring

In order to understand functions better I was advised to refactor the String.prototype.split() method. This isn't for school, I'm self-studying. I thought it was pretty straight forward but after four hours I'm disheartened that I'm not able to get this to work. Here's what I have so far:

```
var myString = "this is a sentence";
var split = function(string, splitParameter) {
var splitArray = [];
var stringElement = "";
var splitter = ""; 
var j = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
  if (string[i] !== splitParameter) {
      stringElement += string[i];
      splitArray[j] = stringElement;
  }else {
      j++;
      splitter += string[i];
  }
  return splitArray;
}


console.log(split(myString," "));
```

I'm having trouble figuring out what to do with the splitParameter argument. When I passed in " " as in the code I pasted above I get:

```
["this", "thisis", "thisisa", "thisisasentence"]
```

when I change the splitParameter to "" I get:

```
["this is a sentence"]
```

and when I pass in "t" I get:

```
[1: "his a sen", 2: "his is a senence"]
```

Can somebody help me get on the right track with what I'm doing? I'm trying to learn how to think about things functionally and use algorithmic reasoning and I can't make heads nor tails of what to do about the delimiter bit of the original split method.

Thanks.

Comment: If the objective is to learn, you're best off just continuing to work with it. Use the debugger built into your browser to help; that way, you can execute each line of code one-at-a-time, look at the values of variables, etc.

Comment: @phizzy check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ec56xw8L/

Comment: You never reset `stringElement` to the empty string in your loop. Do that and it'll work.

Comment: Notice that the real `.split()` method can also split on strings (not single characters) and regular expressions. But I guess this goes beyond your exercise.

Comment: Thanks guys! Now it seems so blindingly obvious, what I was missing. @Bergi --- if I wanted to replicate that functionality of the real `.split( )` method and split on strings...how might I go about this? Sounds like it's time to start learning about regular expressions...

Comment: If you wanted to replicate the functionality of the real split, you may want to have a look at the [real specification algorithm](http://es5.github.io/#x15.5.4.14)

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys I'm new to programming and still learning myself and want to share my understanding about this problem. gladly accept suggestion and criticism about my solution.

```
let sentence = 'this is a sentence';

const cutString = (sentence, splitParameter) => {
storedString = '';
arrayString = [];

    for (let i = 0; i<sentence.length; i++) {
        if (sentence[i] !== splitParameter) {
            storedString+=sentence[i];  
        } else if (sentence[i] === splitParameter) {
            arrayString.push(storedString);
            storedString = '';
            continue;
        }
    }

    if(storedString !== '') {
        arrayString.push(storedString);
    }

    return arrayString;
}

console.log(cutString(sentence, ' '));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let str = "hi ho*w are yo*u";

function split(str, sp){
    let temp = "";
    let splitArray = [];
    for(let i=0; i<str.length; i++){
        if(str[i] != sp){
            temp+= str[i];
            if(str[i+1] == sp || i ==str.length-1){
                splitArray.push(temp);
                temp = "";
            }
        }
    }
    return splitArray;
}

console.log(split(str, "*"));     // return['hi', 'ho*w', 'are', 'yo*u']
console.log(split(str, " "));     // returns ['hi', 'ho*w', 'are' 'yo*u']
```